# Tensorflow tries to use more memory than the profiler indicates it should

Tags: tensorflow

I have implemented SSD (Single Shot Detector) in Tensorflow.

During inference, I'm loading the frozen graph as follows:

```
    def load_graph(filename):
        with tf.gfile.FastGFile(filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        img, box, cls, val = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='',
            return_elements=['input:0', 'pred/box:0', 'pred/cls:0', 'pred/val:0']
        )
        return img, box, cls, val
```

So that no unnecessary operations will tag along.

However, when I was running the usage script, like so:

```
    _box, _cls, _val = sess.run([box, cls, val],{img: np.expand_dims(image_data,0)},
```

(i.e. I'm only using a batch size of one)

I noticed that tensorflow complained about memory allocation:

```
2017-07-08 20:38:46.389877: W 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator 
(GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.05GiB. The caller 
indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be 
performance gains if more memory is available.
```

So I decided to profile the operations, and got the following result:

[image: Profiled Graph]

As you can see, none of the operations are claiming more than 75MB.

Where is this discrepancy coming from?

When I control the amount of memory allocation, like this:

```
    gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True, per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.1)
    config = tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True, gpu_options=gpu_options)
```

Tensorflow still complains about the amount of memory available, but I don't see any critical hits in the performance (i.e. it always runs in about 8 ms, regardless of allowed memory allocated)

When I allow it to grow until Tensorflow seems satisfied, it grows to about 6.7GB.

I don't understand what is causing this behavior to occur. Where is this discrepancy coming from?

Comment: Some ops make exploratory allocations for optional scratch space (they can work without it, e.g. [conv](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops_gpu.h#L54)). Failed allocations may not show up in the profile. Hard to say more without a reproduction. Totally possible that the scratch space isn't helpful in this case (in which case it's fine to ignore the warning).

Answer (score 0):

The warning you report says that allocation on device memory failed and happened on host memory instead;

However, in your tensorboard screenshot, you only show device memory (the `gpu:0` check box). You need to check the `cpu:0` checkbox to also debug CPU operations.

Now, given that you get fast computations in that situation comparable to when it is allocated on the device, and given the size of the allocation (2GB), and given the position of the greyed-out boxes in your tensorboard snapshot, I suspect this tensor holds input data, and that only slices are sent to the GPU as batches. I would say this is fine.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm only sending a single batch at a time, and this batch merely contains one Float32 tensor of 300x300x3 (the image). It doesn't seem plausible that a single image would demand an allocation size of 2GB.

Comment: What does tensorboard display when you check that `cpu:0` box?

Comment: It mostly looks the same. When I only look at CPU ops, they only take up memory in the order of ~23 KB maximum.